# Select object by pstypenames powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I am creating a script to import a file server configuration, which I have exported to an XML file.

This XML file contains 3 objects, 2 custom objects, and 1 deserialized COMobject with the configurations to import:

[image]

I need to select the COM object (the object with the `SmtpServer` property) but I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this.

```
    $importedServerConfig = Import-Clixml -Path ("C:\empty\ServerConfigurations.xml")
    $COMObject = $importedServerConfig|Where-Object{$_.notification -eq "notification"}
    $COMObject
```

With this code I can select the psobject by its property value, but this doesn't work with the COMobject.

I am trying to filter with the method .gettype() but this doesn't work on COMobject, so I am using pstypenames.

[image: the available properties]

```
$importedServerConfig = Import-Clixml -Path ("C:\empty\ServerConfigurations.xml")
$COMObject = $importedServerConfig|Where-Object{$_.pstypenames -eq "Deserialized.System.__ComObject"}
$COMObject
```

My question is: Is there a way to select a specific COMObject using the `pstypenames` property in this XML file?

Comment: `$importedServerConfig | ? PSTypeNames -contains Deserialized.System.__ComObject`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral); here's what I ended up using:

```
$importedServerConfig = Import-Clixml -Path 'C:\empty\ServerConfigurations.xml'
$COMObject = $importedServerConfig | ? { $_.PSTypeNames -contains 'Deserialized.System.__ComObject' } 
$COMObject
```